# I'm trying to filter a date range by day of month and day of week - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: filtering, date-and-time

I am trying to generate a list of dates that match two criteria: they have to all be the first of the month, and they have to be a particular day of the week, Sunday in my case.

The code I have written is this:

`Select[DayRange[{1901, 1, 1}, {2000, 12, 31}], DayName[#] == Sunday && # == {_, _, 1} &]`

I.e. I want to `Select` only those days in between the `DayRange` 1 january 1901 and 31 December 2000 that match the criteria of being a `Sunday` as well as (`&&`) being the first of the month (`{_, _, 1}`).

However, this function just outputs an empty list.

I'm still new to Mathematica, but in as far as I can see everything here should work fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `# == {_, _, 1}` should use `MatchQ` instead of `==`.

Comment: Ah thank you! Is that because the `# == {_, _, 1}` form cannot interpret patterns?

Comment: Think of patterns like regexes. Your expression isn't "equal" to a regex. Your expression  "matches" it.

Comment: Yes.  `==` is for numbers and equations (i.e. math), `===` is for testing if expressions are structurally identical (i.e. programming only, no math), MatchQ is for pattern matching.

Comment: Got it. Thanks @belisarius! And @Szabolcs, you've been extremely helpful to me the past few days!

Comment: @anon: the construct you're using is much slower than needed - see answer

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Select[Cases[DayRange[{1901, 1, 1}, {2000, 12, 31}], {_, _, 1}], DayName[#] == Sunday &]
```

or more concisely:

```
Cases[DayRange[{1901, 1, 1}, {2000, 12, 31}], d : {_, _, 1} /; DayName[d] == Sunday]
```

Does it. If you want to keep it all in a select,

```
Select[DayRange[{1901, 1, 1}, {2000, 12, 31}], (DayName[#] == Sunday && MatchQ[#, {_, _, 1}]) &]
```

Does the same, but slower.

By far the faster:

```
Cases[DayRange[{1901, 1, 1}, {2000, 12, 31}, Sunday], {_, _, 1}]
```

Edit: Per comment below, with changes in later versions of Mathematica, the last example becomes:

```
Cases[DayRange[{1900, 1, 1}, {2000, 12, 31}, Sunday], d_ /; DateValue[d, "Day"] == 1]
```

I will revisit when time permits to include modified versions of other examples and compare performance, along with experimenting with new date function characteristics to determine if a yet more efficient implementation exists.

Comment: Thank you @rasher! This was my first foray into pattern matching - I'm still not clear exactly how patterns and forms work, but your answer (especially the second form) gave me a better understanding

Comment: @anon: Take a look also at the docs for `DayRange`: using the construct of the last in my answer is over 100X faster, since it lets the low-level code of `DayRange` filter out the "Sunday" requirement...

Comment: @rasher just edited typographical error (-> concisely): am learning from and enjoying your answers

Comment: @ubpdqn: Thanks for edit & kind words - not so sure there's anything to learn from me other than I'm a pour speller ;-}

Comment: @rasher always learning...MSE good diversion from 'real world' at present :)

Comment: Five years elapsed since this answer  but with MMA 11.3 none of these lines of code work anymore .  With the versions of MMA I kept, I checked it's quite OK with V9, but goes wrong from V10.0 . Can you give an update ?

Comment: @SigisK - see tail of post for update of one example, will revise rest when time permits.

Comment: @Sigis: you need to adapt to whether you are using `DateRange[]` or `DayRange[]`, since the former returns lists and the latter returns `DateObject[]`s. For instance: `Select[dl, DateValue[#, "Day"] == 1 && DayName[#] === Sunday &]` will work for both `dl = DayRange[{1901, 1, 1}, {2000, 12, 31}]` and `dl = DateRange[{1901, 1, 1}, {2000, 12, 31}]`, but `Select[Cases[dl, {_, _, 1, __}], DayName[#] === Sunday &]` will only work for the `DateRange[]` result.

Comment: By adapting this answer `Select[DayRange[{1901, 1, 1}, {2000, 12, 31}], (DayName[#] == Sunday && MatchQ[#, {_, _, 1}]) &]`  not valid with V11.3  to 
 `Pick[#, {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, 1] & /@  
 Select[DateList /@ 
   DayRange[{1990, 1, 1}, {2000, 12, 31}], (DayName[#] == Sunday && 
     MatchQ[#, {_, _, 1, _, _, _}]) &] `  it becomes compatible with it. I find it rather verbose. To me MMA lacks the possibility to match patterns with dateobjets (in `Select`, `Cases`...) and since I haven't seen a post with these keywords on SE I may add one about it.

Answer (score 2):

I have voted for rasher's excellent answer but just to illustrate `Pick`:

```
With[{dr = DayRange[{1901, 1, 1}, {2000, 12, 31},Sunday]},
 Pick[dr, Last@# == 1 & /@ dr]]
```